# Trying to install bcrypt & command line throwing errors

Tags: pip, ubuntu-14.04, bcrypt

I am running ubuntu 14.04. I open the commanding and use the following command...

```
pip install bcrypt
```

I get the following error...

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_alopex/bcrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VGb_HL-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_alopex/bcrypt
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpOURwCc
```

If you would like the debug log, ask and I will provide (it is super long).

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install bcrypt with apt-get:

```
apt-get install bcrypt
```